# Function to load PNG Image from ResourceStream returns nothing

Tags: image, delphi, resources

In Delphi 10.1 Berlin, I'm trying to change a picture on a form by loading a PNG image from a resource.
I've followed this:
[Load image from embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805372/load-image-from-embedded-resource)
and used a TWICImage to automatically handle different possible image formats.
In this case I specifically want to use a PNG for transparency.

For some reason the function I've created returns nothing.
However, if I call `result.savetofile('test.png')` within the function the resource is succesfully saved, which verifies that the resource exists in the EXE and has been found.

```
function LoadImageResource(NativeInstance: NativeUInt; ImageResource: string): TWICImage;
var
   Strm: TResourceStream;
   WICImage: TWICImage;

begin

  Strm := TResourceStream.Create(NativeInstance, ImageResource, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Strm.Position := 0;
    WICImage := TWICImage.Create;
    try
      WICImage.LoadFromStream(Strm);
      result :=  WICImage; //these return empty
      result.savetofile('test.png'); //this succesfully saves the resource to disk
    finally
      WICImage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Outside of the function, if I attempt to assign the image by calling for example `Image1.picture.assign(LoadFromResource(...))` or `Image1.picture.graphic := LoadFromResource(...)` nothing gets assigned. And If I then call `Image1.savetofile('test.png')` I get an access violation error.

What might I be missing?

Comment: You're free-ing the WICImage that you're returning as the result. I'm surprised your app does not crash as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are destroying the image that you return. It's important to understand that classes are reference types in Delphi. So after the assignment to `Result`, in your code, you still have only a single instance, but two references to that same single instance.

You need to remove the call to `Free`.

```
function LoadImageResource(Module: NativeUInt; const ResName: string): TWICImage;
var
  Strm: TResourceStream;
begin
  Strm := TResourceStream.Create(Module, ResName, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Result := TWICImage.Create;
    Result.LoadFromStream(Strm);
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

A little tweak is needed to make the function exception safe:

```
function LoadImageResource(Module: NativeUInt; const ResName: string): TWICImage;
var
  Strm: TResourceStream;
begin
  Strm := TResourceStream.Create(Module, ResName, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Result := TWICImage.Create;
    try
      Result.LoadFromStream(Strm);
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When you call the function it behaves like a constructor. It either succeeds and returns a new instance, handing over ownership to the caller. Or it raises an exception. Accordingly I would name the function `CreateImageFromResource`.

Comment: Also note that both `Image1.Picture.Assign(LoadFromResource(...))` and `Image1.Picture.Graphic := LoadFromResource(...)` have memory leaks. `TPicture` will make a *copy* of the `TWICImage` that gets assigned to it. The caller must `Free` the original `TWICImage` that `LoadFromResource()` returns: `Img := LoadFromResource(...); try Image1.Picture.Assign(Img); {Image1.Picture.Graphic := Img;} finally Img.Free;` I would instead suggest passing the `TPicture` into `LoadImageResource()` and let it load+assign the picture as needed, no need to return anything to the caller.

Comment: Thank you guys. Especially you David for the explanation on references and copies. That makes a lot more sense to me. I was concerned that not calling free within the function would have lead to memory leaks.
Thanks Remy for the tip on passing the Tpicture to the function. I've succesfully implemented it.